# Why ASPX page gets malformed when user enter "//" after page url

Tags: asp.net

[image][image]

I have a simple ASPX with a Master page. It is a standard page created when you use

visual studio express 2012>> New Website(file system)>>ASP.NET forms website (select master)>>

Its just fresh the way IDE creates it. When I view the "Default.aspx" page it displays normally on the browser.

Even if I type "localhost:xxxxx/Default.Aspx/" its displayed normally.

But if I type "localhost:xxxxx/Default.Aspx//" its malformed.

Can anyone explain why the page is malformed if more than one "/" is suffixed in the URL?
Is there any solution to prevent malformed page?

Comment: Sure. Don't use `//`.

Comment: I am not using "//" I am just trying to see how a user may play with url.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Frankly, if a user messes around with a URL, they wouldn't be surprised to get a 404.

Comment: @Moe I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: What does "malformed" mean? That is rather broad and isn't a proper description.

Comment: Even the one `/` make the file to look like directory. So here is your reason. Also any rewrite module that you may use, can confuse with the two `//`. Your message is probably that can not find the page... If you search to correct the user input, get the url from the page not found, make some analysis and suggest him some alternative.

Comment: My be its looking for a directory name (between //)

Comment: @Oded the menu on master page starts looking like a bulleted list, Log in looks like a bullet

Comment: Have you looked at the source HTML to determine what is different? Did you figure out why?

Comment: I have added pics to the question

Comment: Please use `Fiddler` and you'll see, that CSS files are not loaded correctly. You should use absolute URLs in css paths.

Answer (score 0):

When you route an url like this:

```
localhost:xxxxx/Default.Aspx//
```

Actually you route these addresses four fetch Resources (like image files, css files, and so on)

```
localhost:xxxxx/Default.Aspx//Resources/Scripts/jquery.js
localhost:xxxxx/Default.Aspx//Resources/Images/pic1.jpg
localhost:xxxxx/Default.Aspx//Resources/styles/mystyle.css
```

and naturally these address are wrong for routing your resources, so browser can't fetch resources of page and only Default.aspx file fetch without dependencies.(you  can check this with fiddler Or
IE> F12 >network> url column)